# How to implement the Paypal Mobile Express Checkout..?

Tags: php, paypal, payment

I need a guidance to implement the Paypal Mobile Express Checkout in PHP.

I am looking for sample code, and documentation, to implement it.

Please advise me.

My site was lacking this functionality, so I need a quick response from an expert.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 6):

> Mobile Express Checkout is PayPal’s
>   Express Checkout service tailored to
>   mobile devices. Mobile Express
>   Checkout screens are optimized for
>   webkit browsers for iPhone and
>   Android.  It is easy to transition
>   your desktop checkout experience to
>   mobile devices.  To help with this
>   transition PayPal has some best
>   practices you should review.  These
>   suggestions can improve the user
>   experience and result it higher
>   conversion rates.

There is lot about mobile express checkout

https://www.x.com/blogs/Sidney/2011/04/15/mobile-express-checkout-quick-start

As well as lot about this payment gatway and sample code

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECOnMobileDevices

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_code

Answer (score 0):

I found this today while also searching for PHP code for the PayPal MEC http://code.google.com/p/paypalmobile/.  It was exactly what I was looking for and hopefully will help you as well.